# Kotlin: Post request with basic authentication and parameters resulted server error

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I am connecting to a restful service with basic authorization using kotlin android app. The `Authorization` header is checked. The `params` are checked. `url` is checked. Also Firewall is checked.
But I'm getting `com.android.volley.ServerError` error.
This values are OK in `Postman`. Here is part of my code:

```
            val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextResponse)

            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
            val url = ApiUrls.CustomerAuthenticate;

            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, url,
                Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    textView.text = "That didn't work!"
                }) {
                override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                    val authorizationString = String.format(
                        "%s:%s",
                        "username",
                        "password"
                    )
                    val authorizationByte = authorizationString.toByteArray()
                    val base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(authorizationByte, Base64.NO_WRAP)
                    headers["Authorization"] = String.format("Basic %s", base64Encoded)
                    return headers
                }

                override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params["username"] = "username"
                    params["password"] = "password"

                    return params
                }
            }

            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(
                DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    45000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
                )
            )

            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some struggling found the answer. Just replace

```
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params["username"] = "username"
            params["password"] = "password"

            return params
        }
```

with

```
                override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                    return "application/json"
                }

                override fun getBody(): ByteArray {
                    val params2 = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params2.put("username", "username")
                    params2.put("password", "password")
                    return JSONObject(params2 as Map<*, *>).toString().toByteArray()
                }
```